# How do you pass an output parameter from vb.net to a mysql stored procedure?

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net

I am using the .net connector with mysql 5.5. When I try to call a stored procedure with an "out" parameter, I get the message `OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine` *name* `is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger` at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

What is wrong?

vb code:

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand("call testme(@id, @count)", conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id) ' "id" and "count" are integer variables
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count)
cmd.Parameters("@count").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

mysql stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testme(in taxid integer, out imageDescCount integer)
BEGIN
set imageDescCount = 23;
End
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this

Create Stored Procedure in MySQl like

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `tempdb`.`GetCity` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `tempdb`.`GetCity` 
(IN cid INT,
 OUT cname VarChar(50)
)

BEGIN

  SET cname = (SELECT CityName FROM `City` WHERE CID = cid);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And Your vb.net code like

```
Dim conn As  New MySqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=tempdb;port=3306;password=******;"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()

conn.Open()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "GetCity"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", "1")
cmd.Parameters("@cid").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", MySqlDbType.String)
cmd.Parameters("@cname").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Console.WriteLine("City Name: " & cmd.Parameters("@cname").Value) //Access Your Output Value
```

Let me know if you have any problem...

Thanks

Comment: Breaking out the cmd. parts like that fixed the problem, even without altering the stored procedure and with integer parameters. (MySqlDbType.String generated an error, but changing it to a string variable worked OK.) Thanks!